# What's wrong with my durand-kerner implementation?

Tags: c++

Implementing this simple root-finding algorithm. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durand%E2%80%93Kerner_method
I cannot for the life of me figure out what's wrong with my implementation. The roots keep blowing up and no sign of convergence. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

typedef complex<double> dcmplx;

dcmplx f(dcmplx x)
{
    // the function we are interested in
    double a4 = 3;
    double a3 = -3;
    double a2 = 1;
    double a1 = 0;
    double a0 = 100;

    return a4 * pow(x,4) + a3 * pow(x,3) + a2 * pow(x,2) + a1 * x + a0;
}


int main()
{   

dcmplx p(.9,2);
dcmplx q(.1, .5);
dcmplx r(.7,1);
dcmplx s(.3, .5);

dcmplx p0, q0, r0, s0;

int max_iterations = 20;
bool done = false;
int i=0;

while (i<max_iterations && done == false)
{   
    p0 = p;
    q0 = q;
    r0 = r;
    s0 = s;


p = p0 - f(p0)/((p0-q0)*(p0-r0)*(p0-s0));
q = q0 - f(q0)/((q0-p)*(q0-r0)*(q0-s0));
r = r0 - f(r0)/((r0-p)*(r0-q)*(r0-s0));
s = s0 - f(s0)/((s0-p)*(s0-q)*(s0-r));

    // if convergence within small epsilon, declare done
    if (abs(p-p0)<1e-5 && abs(q-q0)<1e-5 && abs(r-r0)<1e-5 && abs(s-s0)<1e-5)
        done = true;

    i++;
}

cout<<"roots are :\n";
cout << p << "\n";
cout << q << "\n";
cout << r << "\n";
cout << s << "\n";
cout << "number steps taken: "<< i << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A half year late: The solution to the enigma is that the denominator should be an approximation of the derivative of the polynomial, and thus needs to contain the leading coefficient a4 as factor.

Alternatively, one can divide the polynomial value by a4 in the return statement, so that the polynomial is effectively normed, i.e., has leading coefficient 1.

Note that the example code in wikipedia by Bo Jacoby is the Seidel-type variant of the method, the classical formulation is the Jordan-like method where all new approximations are simultaneously computed from the old approximation. Seidel can have faster convergence than the order 2 that the formulation as a multidimensional Newton method provides for Jacobi.

However, for large degrees Jacobi can be accelerated using fast polynomial multiplication algorithms for the required multi-point evaluations of polynomial values and the products in the denominators.

Comment: haha, yes that was what it turned out to be (a half year ago). thanks anyways!

Comment: Uups, I must have jumped over your answer directly to the second answer. Do you think that this condition should be given more weight in the wikipedia article? At the moment, it is explicit only in the last sentence of the introduction. -- Is the second part of the article sufficient to get the idea for the implementation of the general case with arbitrary degrees?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the problem was that the coefficients of an N-degree polynomial have to be specified as

1*x^N + a*x^(N-1) + b*x^(N-2) ... etc + z;

where 1 is the coefficient of the largest degree term. Otherwise the first root will never converge.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't implemented for formulae correctly. For instance

```
s = s0 - f(s0)/((s0-p0)*(s0-q0)*(s0-r0));
```

should be

```
s = s0 - f(s0)/((s0-p)*(s0-q)*(s0-r));
```

Look again at the wiki article

Comment: cheers, thanks for catching that error. i made the code edits in my question. but still producing blow-up results. let me know if i've mis-typed it again

Comment: Nothing leaps out at me. There's a worked example in the wiki article. I suggest you add some print statements to your loop and compare the numbers you see with the example in the wiki and see exactly where you diverge.